# Send FirebaseRecyclerOption/Recycler View via Intent to Another Activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating dog health app which has a login activity, when a user is signing up, they can add their dogs to their account, which is stored in my Firebase Realtime Database like so:

[image]

Each dog is created using a `Dog` constructor, and the `name` element saves as the node value within the database. I also have a RecyclerAdapter which lists each dog under the logged in user (owner), these elements are clickable and take you to the DogProfile activity.

Within the DogProfile activity, I have the stored dogs details listed within `TextView`'s, however when I click a specific dog in my ChooseDog activity, it only shows for one dog (in my case, `Finn`). I am wondering how to find the dogs `name` (node value) from the button, pass it via an `intent` to my `DogProfile`, and display the database information relating to that particular dog, this needs to be done dynamically which is where I am struggling.

I have set up my intents properly as far as I can see, however the data isn't changing depending on which dog button is clicked.

I am not receiving any errors, but both buttons (Moo and Finn in this case), are both returning data from the Finn node.

Here's what I have..

**DogProfile activity**

```
  private void getDogData() {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(uid).child("dogs");

    String dogsName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(dogsName);

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);

                if (name.equals(dogsName)) {
                    String dogBreed = ds.child("breed").getValue(String.class);
                    String dogAge = ds.child("age").getValue(String.class);
                    String gender = ds.child("gender").getValue(String.class);
                    String dogWeight = ds.child("weight").getValue(String.class);
                    String neutered = ds.child("neutered").getValue(String.class);

                    dogName.setText(name);
                    breed.setText(dogBreed);
                    age.setText(dogAge);
                    dogGender.setText(gender);
                    weight.setText(dogWeight);
                    isNeutered.setText(neutered);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DogProfile.this, "Please try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

**ChooseDog activity**

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Dog> options
            = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Dog>()
            .setQuery(databaseReference, Dog.class)
            .build();

    dogUserAdapter = new DogUserAdapter(options);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(dogUserAdapter);

    ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(
            new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                    TextView dogName = findViewById(R.id.dogName);
                    getDogData();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseDog.this, DogProfile.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", dogName.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Firebase DB but I can suggest the solution. In the ChooseDog activity, after a user clicks on an item, you should get their value, in this case, the dog's name, and pass it to the intent. In the DogProfile activity, you should fetch the specific dog's profile based on that name.

Comment: Thank you @Basu, that sounds helpful, I will see what I can do. I will come back if I have any questions.

Comment: @Basu I have added what I am trying, I'm really unsure what to do. I have no idea how to retrieve the name from the database in this activity, I have got it in other activities but the methods don't seem to work here? I thought to maybe add `String dogName = databaseReference.child("name").getValue(String.class);` but I get an unsolvable error on `getValue`

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question. Is there any way you can reduce the amount of code to the minimum needed for the question? It really helps if we don't have to dig through UI code to find a database problem (or vice versa).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have reduced the code to what I feel is minimum. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show the details for one dog, based on a property of that dog, you should [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data):

```
private void getDogData() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(uid).child("dogs");
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("name").equalTo("moo");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        ...
```

Comment: Would I still need to pass the details from the intent over to the DogProfile? I have here `equalTo(String.valueOf(dogName))` but I don't think thats correct..

Comment: Basically I have no idea how to get the dogs name from the `TextView` on the `RecyclerView` to the name `TextView` on the `DogProfile` activity..

Comment: So that seems unrelated to the database then? This is precisely why I asked you to minimize the context, as I am not nearly as fluent with Android parameter passing as I am with Firebase.

Comment: Potentially.. I have included the Intent above if its of any use to you. My `RecyclerView` gets the name from Firebase and displays it to the UI. I am unsure how to pass that over to my `DogProfile` to retrieve the name then show the correct details - HOWEVER, your query stuff was very helpful, I just need to figure out how to substitute the `equalsTo` method..

Comment: I have made some additions, still no joy, but if its of any use to you to help me, please let me know as I've run out of options.