# Android Intent not transferring data to another activity? Firebase Data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I asked about this yesterday but never had much luck, I thought I would re-ask with a clearer outline of what I am trying to do..

**Firstly, here is my Firebase hierarchy**
[image]

I have a RecyclerViewAdapter/View which finds the Uid, and if the user has dogs listed on their 'account' then it will display a list of dogs, in this case `finn` and `moo`, this section is my first activity - `ChooseDog`. Each dog is clickable, and after clicking, it will take you to the second activity - `DogProfile` - where I am displaying details from each particular dog.
My problem is that the profile is only picking a random dog (if there is more than one) and displaying those details, I cannot seem to differentiate the results.

I want to take the name displayed on the card/button on `ChooseDog`, send it to the `DogProfile` via an `intent`, then use that name to show the correct details for the chosen dog. I'm quite new to this, but feel like I've done everything somewhat correctly? Any help is appreciated. I have been able to find the details when declaring the name explicitly, but not when trying to retrieve the name from the card.

**ChooseDog** (1st Activity)

```
TextView dogName;

databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(uid).child("dogs");
dogName = findViewById(R.id.dogName);

    ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(
            new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                    getDogData();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseDog.this, DogProfile.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", dogName.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );

 private void getDogData() {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String dogName = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }
```

**DogProfile** (2nd Activity)

```
private void getDogData() {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(uid).child("dogs");

    String dogsName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(dogsName);

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);

             
                    String dogBreed = ds.child("breed").getValue(String.class);
                    String dogAge = ds.child("age").getValue(String.class);
                    String gender = ds.child("gender").getValue(String.class);
                    String dogWeight = ds.child("weight").getValue(String.class);
                    String neutered = ds.child("neutered").getValue(String.class);

                    dogName.setText(name);
                    breed.setText(dogBreed);
                    age.setText(dogAge);
                    dogGender.setText(gender);
                    weight.setText(dogWeight);
                    isNeutered.setText(neutered);
           
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

**Logcat**

```
2021-07-29 10:13:49.990 17941-17941/com.example.doggo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.doggo, PID: 17941
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.doggo.ChooseDog$1.onItemClicked(ChooseDog.java:69)
        at com.example.doggo.ItemClickSupport$1.onClick(ItemClickSupport.java:16)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

Comment: are you getting the dogname from the textfield and then sending it to the next activity or are you retrieving the dogname from db and sending it?

Comment: I get the dog name from the database, display it on the card text view (first activity), and basically I want to check in my second activity if that text view matches the name in the database, show that particular dogs details, hope that makes sense @PeterHaddad

Comment: What exactly didn't work from Frank van Puffelen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68567239/5246885)?

Comment: His answer works, but its static, I need to pull data dynamically, so `equalTo("moo")` needs to find the name from the `textView` of the button. I don't know if I've just been staring at it too long, or I've put something in the wrong place but every so often I get a `NullPointerException` so definitely not pulling something from the right place. @AlexMamo

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also indicate at which particular line of code are you getting the NullPointerException?

Comment: It doesn't crash at the moment.. I have changed it so much since it last gave me the exception, and it does show details for the dog, but just one random dog (right now it is only showing Finns details no matter which button I press). However I remember it was to do with setting the text of the String of name?? I'll see if I can recreate it.

Comment: @Caitlin aren't you getting the `dogName` from the textview by doing this: `dogName.getText().toString()` and sending it?

Comment: @PeterHaddad, yes but it's not working for some reason

Comment: @AlexMamo, just updating with the stack trace now

Comment: @Caitlin make sure you have id `dogName` on the textview in your xml file that's used for this activity

Comment: @PeterHaddad, both id's are dogName, my profile activity was a different ID but same error after rectifying.

Comment: Okay so my `choose_dog` XML file doesn't actually contain the ID for the `ChooseDog` java class, this is actually stored in my card view which is `Dog.xml` due to the `RecyclerView` @AlexMamo @PeterHaddad

Comment: There is a line in my DogProfile:  `Query query = databaseReference.child("dogs").equalTo(intentName);`, my database ref already points to the child("dogs") I wonder if this is an issue?

Answer (score 1):

This answer based on your last few questions , hope this will help you. Today I will not talk about firebase authentication or store data part , because you already done that . I understand that at first you want to retrieve data and want show it in `RecyclerView` , then if user click on these specific data/item you want to show details through `DogProfile`. Almost of your code fine , in `getDogData()` method you should just add `dogName` with ArrayList and populate the Adapter . Then pass the data trough intent , use `adapter.getItem(position)` instead `dogName` variable.

Just follow these code-

1. `ChooseDog` class

   ```
          public class ChooseDog extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private ArrayList<String> dogList;
    private String dogName;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_dog);

        // dogName = findViewById(R.id.dogName);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("dogs");
        getDogData();

        dogList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dogList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dogList);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);


    }


    private void getDogData() {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    dogName = ds.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    dogList.add(dogName);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You Selected " + adapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseDog.this, DogProfile.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", adapter.getItem(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   }
   ```
2. `activity_choose_do.xml`

   ```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChooseDog">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dogList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
3. `MyRecyclerViewAdapter` class

   ```
    public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> zData;
    private LayoutInflater zInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.zInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.zData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = zInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String dog = zData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(dog);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return zData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dogsName);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return zData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
   }
   ```
4. `recyclerview_layout.xml`

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dogsName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
   ```
5. `DogProfile` class , in this some wrong cast I was found , such as Spinner as TextView . Here fixed copy -

   ```
    public class DogProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    TextView breed;
    Spinner ageDropdown, genderDropdown, weightDropdown, neuteredDropdown; //zi
    String uid;
    String dogId;
    private EditText dogName; //zi

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dog_profile);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        uid = currentUser.getUid();

        dogName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        breed = findViewById(R.id.breed);
        ageDropdown = findViewById(R.id.age);
        genderDropdown= findViewById(R.id.gender);
        weightDropdown = findViewById(R.id.weight);
        neuteredDropdown = findViewById(R.id.neutered);

        getDogData();

    }

    private void getDogData() {

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("dogs");

        String dogsName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(dogsName);

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String name = (String) ds.child("name").getValue();

                    if (name.equals(dogsName)) {
                        String dogBreed = (String) ds.child("breed").getValue();
                        String dogAge = (String) ds.child("age").getValue();
                        String gender = (String) ds.child("gender").getValue();
                        String dogWeight = (String) ds.child("weight").getValue();
                        String neutered = (String) ds.child("neutered").getValue();

                        dogName.setText(name);
                        breed.setText(dogBreed);


        ArrayAdapter<String> ageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Collections.singletonList(dogAge));
        ageAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ageDropdown.setAdapter(ageAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> weightAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Collections.singletonList(dogWeight));
        weightAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        weightDropdown.setAdapter(weightAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Collections.singletonList(gender));
        genderAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        genderDropdown.setAdapter(genderAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> neuteredAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Collections.singletonList(neutered));
        neuteredAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        neuteredDropdown.setAdapter(neuteredAdapter);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(DogProfile.this, "Please try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }


   }
   ```
6. `dog_profile.xml`

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DogProfile">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="560dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:autofillHints="age"
            android:hint="Age"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.085"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.353" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/weight"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:autofillHints="weight"
            android:hint="Weight (kg)"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.901"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.356" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breed"
            android:layout_width="347dp"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:autofillHints="breed"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="Breed"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.434"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.196" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="354dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:autofillHints="Name"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.032" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:autofillHints="gender"
            android:hint="Gender"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.086"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.532" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/neutered"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:autofillHints="neutered"
            android:hint="Neutered?"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.901"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.535" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Daily Exercise Goal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.058"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.665" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.624" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you think this answer useful , you may accept this by ✓